# Unable to post message to https://player.vimeo.com. Recipient has origin https://tpc.googlesyndication.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I am trying to play a video using vimeo player online on safari browser on mac OS. But when I post the 'ready' request, I get an error Error which says

> Unable to post message to https://player.vimeo.com .  Recipient has
>   origin https://tpc.googlesyndication.com.

This is how I call the vimeo functions

```
 var player = $('iframe');
        var playerOrigin = '*';
        var status = $('.status');
        // Listen for messages from the player
        if (window.addEventListener) {
            window.addEventListener('message', onMessageReceived, false);
        }
        else {
            window.attachEvent('onmessage', onMessageReceived, false);
        }
        // Handle messages received from the player
        function onMessageReceived(event) {
            // Handle messages from the vimeo player only
            if (!(/^https?:\/\/player.vimeo.com/).test(event.origin)) {
                return false;
            }
            if (playerOrigin === '*') {
                playerOrigin = event.origin;
            }
            var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
            switch (data.event) {
                case 'ready':
                    onReady();
                    break;

                case 'playProgress':
                    onPlayProgress(data.data);
                    break;

                case 'pause':
                    onPause(data.data);
                    break;

                case 'seek':
                    onseekTo(data.data);
                    break;

                case 'finish':
                    onFinish();
                    break;
            }
        }
        // Helper function for sending a message to the player
        function post(action, value) {
            var data = {
                method: action
            };
            if (value) {
                data.value = value;
            }
            var message = JSON.stringify(data);
            player[0].contentWindow.postMessage(message, playerOrigin);
        }

        function onReady() {
            $(".loading").show();
            post('addEventListener', 'finish');
            post('addEventListener', 'playProgress');
            post('addEventListener', 'pause');
            post('addEventListener', 'seek');

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the player is rendered via google ad. 
[tpc.googlesyndication](https://support.google.com/google-ads/thread/4757309?hl=en) is google ads platform. 
The ad is wrapping the player. So any `postMessages` go via that, hence scrubbing the actual event origin.

I am facing a similar issue. The stop-gap I have is to use `'*'` (I cringe at the idea of having a wildcard target; but I don't have a cleaner solution yet)